# Issue with understanding fencepost handling with merge-sort

Tags: java, arrays, mergesort, fencepost

Fencepost (AKA An off-by-one error (OBOE), also commonly known as an OBOB (off-by-one bug).

Given an array, I would generally iterate through index 0 to array.length() (Half-open interval).

I've noticed that certain versions of merge-sort require the mid value to be (start+end)/2. And when you calculate the number of elements in the merge process then we sometimes refer to using (end - start) as number of elements or (end - mid + 1). I am not able to intuitively get this? I somehow have difficulty understanding this and feel like am mugging up each time I look at any new implementation.

Can someone provide an intuitive way to understanding how I can apply/recognize a fencepost problem? Is this the same for multi-dimensional arrays?

```
public static BigInteger mergeSort(int[] integerArray, int start, int end) {
    if (start >= end) { // less than equal to is important for cases when start = end = 0
        return BigInteger.valueOf(0);
    }
    int middle = (start + end) / 2;
    BigInteger numInv1 = mergeSort(integerArray, start, middle);
    BigInteger numInv2 = mergeSort(integerArray, middle + 1, end);
    BigInteger numInv3 = runMerge(integerArray, start, middle, end);
    return numInv1.add(numInv2).add(numInv3);
}

private static BigInteger runMerge(int[] integerArray,
                                   int start, int middle, int end) {
    BigInteger numInv = BigInteger.valueOf(0);
    int n1 = middle - start + 1;
    /*
    number of elements in 1st array is middle - start + 1. why ?
    */

    int n2 = end - middle;       // number of elements in 2nd array
    /*
    number of elements in 2nd array is end - middle. why ?
    */

    int []p = new int[n1];
    int []q = new int[n2];
    int i, j, k;
    for (i = 0; i < n1 ; i++) {
        p[i] = integerArray[start + i];
    }
    for (j = 0; j < n2; j++) {
        q[j] = integerArray[middle + j + 1];
        //Why do we do +1 here? because we use 2nd array for mid+1 till end elements
    }
    i = 0;
    j = 0;
    k = start;
    while ( i < n1 && j < n2) {
        if (p[i] <= q[j]) {
            integerArray[k++] = p[i++];
        } else {
            integerArray[k++] = q[j++];
            numInv = numInv.add(BigInteger.valueOf(n1-i));
        }
    }
    while ( i < n1 ) {
        integerArray[k++] = p[i++];
    }
    while ( j < n2 ) {
        integerArray[k++] = q[j++];
    }
    return numInv;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> number of elements in 1st array is middle - start + 1. why?
>   number of elements in 2nd array is end - middle. why?

They are not numbers of elements, they are elements' edge indexes needed to break initial array into smaller arrays. Suppose you have an array to sort:

```
int[] myIntArray = {7,4,3,5,1,12,12,11,0,2};
```

It contains 10 elements but the **indexes** go from 0 to 9. So, in your method `mergeSort(int[] integerArray, int start, int end);` it should be `myIntArray, 0, 9`, not `myIntArray, 1, 10` nor `myIntArray, 1, 9`.

So, assuming we pass arguments like `myIntArray, 0, 9`, lets look into the last (folding direction) call of `mergeSort()` when we have two sorted subarrays:

After calculating middle = (0 + 9) / 2 = 4, we mentally broke our initial array into 2 arrays like this:

`mergeSort(integerArray, start, middle);` where start = 0 and middle = 4 (comprises the items with **indexes** from 0 to 4 - both included: 1,3,4,5,7)

and

`mergeSort(integerArray, middle + 1, end);` where start = middle + 1 = 4 + 1 = 5 and end = 9 (comprises the numbers with **indexes** from 5 to 9 - both included: 0,2,11,12,12).

Here

```
q[j] = integerArray[middle + j + 1];
```

by adding +1 we are getting to the 5th element. Remember that in the stack for the current call variable middle is equal to 4 and this value (4) was passed to `runMerge()`. Value `middle + 1` went to one of the previously finished calls of `mergeSort()`.

The whole proceeding goes on untill we get arrays of size 1 that can be considered sorted and then we start to merge - sure, you already know this. As you can see, those variables - start, middle, end - are the positions (indexes) of elements and not numbers of elements.

The code you posted works fine if you treat arguments as items' positions like `mergeSort(myIntArray, 0, 9);` and not as number of items. In the beginning it should be `array.length() - 1` Hope it helps :)